# xcode error: program received signal SIGABRT, very simple program tho

Tags: xcode, sigabrt

I'm trying to write a program that counts the number of wings my friend eats, while at the same time counting the amount of time that has passed. Fairly simple and I made the program with no errors compiling, but it gives me an error when I go to run it. this is the relevant error (I think):

> 2011-11-16 15:41:31.157 WingChallenge[5530:f803] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[ setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key minutes.'

and here is the relevant code:

```
- (IBAction)wingPlus:(id)sender {

    wings +=1;
     NSString *wingsTemp = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@" %i !", wings];
    self.wingsEaten.text = wingsTemp;

}
- (IBAction)clear:(id)sender {

    wings = 0;
    NSString *wingsClear = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"Back to zero!"];
    self.wingsEaten.text=wingsClear;
}

-(void)countup {
   seconds +=1;
   if (seconds >= 60) {
       seconds=0;
        minutescount +=1;

 }
    minutes.text=[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%i", minutescount];
    secondslabel.text=[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%i", seconds];
}


- (IBAction)startTimer:(id)sender {

   seconds=0;

    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(countup) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}
```

And from the header files:

```
- (IBAction)wingPlus:(id)sender;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *wingsEaten;
- (IBAction)clear:(id)sender;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *minutes;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *secondslabel;
- (IBAction)startTimer:(id)sender;
```

Comment: I just figured it out!

I had two connections under my label...

such a newb... :-(

Comment: +1 Like to read through questions that have Crash log, Code, description. Good job asking first question on SO. Write an answer for this question in Your Answer section then accept it.